# How to configure IntelliJ to show SVN as a repository option alongside CVS , GIT and others?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, version-control, repository

I have IntelliJ in which I want to configure a project through SVN. The VCS Menu doesn't even show SVN as an option. Here are some screenshots of what my instance of IntelliJ is configured with where there is no SVN as an option. There are CVS, Clearcase, etc. but not SVN.

I've searched a lot but all of those links are on how to configure an SVN project provided an SVN option is available in the first place. But in my problem, I need some information on how to enable SVN to be considered as an option by IntelliJ :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the Subversion plugin under Settings | Plugins.

Comment: This worked. I now see SVN options and could configure that repository.